# In the first opening of 'Jujutsu Kaisen', what does the water filling the train that Yuji is riding signify?

Tags: theme-song, symbolism, jujutsu-kaisen

I'm [continuing](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/64114) [to try](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/65838) and fully understand the OPs in *Jujutsu Kaisen*, and right now I'm interested in knowing whether, in the [first OP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v8bZVdTgXoY), there is any deeper significance behind Itadori Yuji riding an empty metro train half-asleep *while being knee-deep in water*.

> [image: Screenshot from the first OP showing the empty metro train filled knee-deep with water. A black-and-white fish swims in the water close to Itadori Yuji.]

I suppose the scene is vaguely unsettling simply because of the way the everyday act of riding a metro train is shown to interact with the supernatural — the knee-deep water filling the train, which is empty except for Yuji, who is somewhere between wakefulness and sleep. But, what is the symbolism behind the water filling the train, specifically?

Curiously, near the very end of the OP, one of Ryomen Sukuna's fingers is shown sinking into the water, and a plant is shown to sprout from it as it sinks deeper.

> [image: Screenshot from the first OP showing one of Sukuna's fingers sinking into the knee-deep water surrounding Itadori Yuji. A plant is shown to start growing from the finger as it sinks.]

Sukuna's fingers are an integral plot point, that much is fine. But why does a plant grow rapidly from the finger when it enters the water? What is this meant to convey?

Comment: [*This might help.*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h8DJwFib0iY)

Answer (score 2):

**I think~**

Being in the water till knees means he has already drowned in the world of Sorcerers and which is causing him unconsciousness because of Sukuna's fingers or Sukuna himself. And the water will rise more with the uprising number of fingers being in-taken by Itadori.

The only one fish in the water signifies Itadori himself being alone trying to fight for his curse(his grandpa's advice). He is all alone into it coz he is the only one who can vessel Sukuna and control it. And the fish turning into a monster/ trying to attack him by jumping is indicating that how this curse will take his own life and how it is, everyday.

The finger as soon as getting into the water resulting in the leaves formation so rapidly means again Itadori's condition. As the fingers go inside his body, it absorbs it in an instant and tries to take control of it by making him stronger coz of sukuna's power.

Hope I at least kinda satisfied your curiosity.